# wondering about the greedy algorithm to the set cover problem

Tags: algorithms

i'm currently learning about the Set-Cover problem and i have a question about it.
Using the greedy algorithm to solve this, some proof says:

Since the optimal solution uses k sets, there must some set that covers at least a $\frac{1}{k}$ of the points. The algorithm chooses the set that covers the most points, so it covers at
least that many. Therefore, after the first iteration of the algorithm, **there are at most $n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$points left.** Why this? What the meaning of $n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$?? and it continue and says that after the second iteration, , there are at most $n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^2$ points left. why? why ^2?

tnx in advance!

Comment: i took it from here if it matters : http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f12/lectures/lect1106.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Note that $n(1-\frac1k)=n-\frac nk$, which may be easier to work with intuitively. Because there is a solution with $k$ sets, there must be at least one set with $\frac nk$ or more points. (If all sets are smaller than that, $k$ sets can't possibly cover everything). This means that the first greedy step will take care of at least $\frac nk$ points, so there are *at most* $n-\frac nk$ points left that need to be covered in later steps.